# Why does the memory allocated get halved when loading a resource for every following request?

Tags: php

While debugging memory allocation, I noticed that the memory usage is halved for every following request.

The script looks like this:

```
<?php

ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');

var_dump(memory_get_usage());

$im = imagecreatefromjpeg('image.jpg');


var_dump(memory_get_usage(true));

imagedestroy($im);
```

First request:

```
/Users/john/code/testing/index.php:5:int 401192
/Users/john/code/testing/index.php:10:int 218103808
```

Second request:

```
/Users/john/code/testing/index.php:5:int 401160
/Users/john/code/testing/index.php:10:int 216006656
```

Third request:

```
/Users/john/code/testing/index.php:5:int 401160
/Users/john/code/testing/index.php:10:int 109051904
```

Fourth request:

```
/Users/john/code/testing/index.php:5:int 401160
/Users/john/code/testing/index.php:10:int 54525952
```

The script is run on PHP 7.1 using the built in web server. (`php -S localhost:8000`)

What's happening here?

Comment: Is is always the same image you are playing with?

Comment: Does not happen like that when I run that code from the command line 4 time using the same image each call. I get exectly the same numbers each time

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes, same image. Yes, when I run in the command line the memory allocated seems to be the same, however, I'm running it through PHP's built in web server and request goes through the web browser.

Comment: There is a lot more (invisible) stuff going on in that environment

Comment: Yeah, you can't rely on running it in the browser. I once spent the whole day chasing a phantom memory leak. Console/cmd is better here.